# android JSONException index out of range

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I have 3 records in my database but only one shows. No idea how to fix the problem, I tried everything. HELP

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    JSONObject jo;
    Teacher teacher;

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray innerJsonArray = response.getJSONArray(i);
            jo = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            int id = jo.getInt("id");
            String name = jo.getString("teacher_name");
            String description = jo.getString("teacher_description");
            String imageUrl = jo.getString("teacher_image_url");

            teacher = new Teacher(name, description, PHP_MYSQL_SITE_URL+imageUrl);
            teachers.add(teacher);
            te.setText(Integer.toString(response.length()));
        }
        //SET SPINNER
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(c, teachers);
        gv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: The error says that you are trying to access a value out of the range of the array size, can you post the full logcat error ?

Comment: there should be 2 for loops , one for   'JSONArray innerJsonArray = response.getJSONArray(i);' and second for 'JSONArray innerJsonArray = response.getJSONArray(j);' that iterates through innerJsonArray

Comment: Can you post the JSON you're trying to parse?

Comment: When i check responce.leght() it tells me its 1. It seems i only get 1 record but when i run the php on the web it gives me all 3 files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there should be 2 for loops , one for `JSONArray innerJsonArray = response.getJSONArray(i);` and second for `JSONArray innerJsonArray = response.getJSONArray(j);` that iterates through innerJsonArray

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

        JSONObject jo;
        Teacher teacher;

        try {

        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray innerJsonArray = response.getJSONArray(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < innerJsonArray.length(); j++) {
                     jo = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                     int id = jo.getInt("id");
                     String name = jo.getString("teacher_name");
                     String description = jo.getString("teacher_description");
                     String imageUrl = jo.getString("teacher_image_url");
                     teacher = new Teacher(name, description, PHP_MYSQL_SITE_URL + imageUrl);
                     teachers.add(teacher);
                     te.setText(Integer.toString(response.length()));
                }
               }
               //SET SPINNER
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(c, teachers);
        gv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Dadran It workd, spent all day on and just like that. THAKS A 1000000000000

Comment: @noob You're mosttt welcome :D since it worked please accept my solution by clicking the tick mark

Comment: sorry first time. how do i do that??